# How can I make match arms recognize value parameter?

Tags: rust, match

I'm trying to swap contents of a struct based on values passed in associated function. However, while using `match`, arms do not seem to recognize the value parameter, and thus arms after first one become unreachable.

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Color {
    pub r: u8,
    pub g: u8,
    pub b: u8,
    pub a: u8,
}

impl Color {
    pub fn swap(mut self, first: u8, second: u8) -> Color {
        let mut swapped = self;

        match self {
            Color { r: first, g, b, a } => swapped.r = second,
            Color { r, g: first, b, a } => swapped.g = second,
            Color { r, g, b: first, a } => swapped.b = second,
            Color { r, b, g, a: first } => swapped.a = second,
        }

        match self {
            Color { r: second, g, b, a } => swapped.r = first,
            Color { r, g: second, b, a } => swapped.g = first,
            Color { r, g, b: second, a } => swapped.b = first,
            Color { r, g, b, a: second } => swapped.a = first,
        }

        self = swapped;
        self

    }
}
```

However, if I put an actual u8 like `Color { r: 10, g,b,a }`, then it works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `first` binding, destructuring the `Color`. To perform variable value comparisons, you need a "match guard" like so:

```
match self {
    Color { r, g, b, a } if r == first => swapped.r = second,
    Color { r, g, b, a } if g == first => swapped.g = second,
    Color { r, g, b, a } if b == first => swapped.b = second,
    Color { r, b, g, a } if a == first => swapped.a = second,
    _ => { /* no match */ },
}
```

The final "match-all" arm is required because the patterns are non-exhaustive, so you need to tell Rust what to do in the case that *none* of the other arms match.  For example, it may be appropriate to panic here to signal bad input, or modify your function to return `Result<Color, SomeErrorType>` and return `Err` from the match-all arm.

Note that since you only use one field in each arm, you can ignore the others:

```
match self {
    Color { r, .. } if r == first => swapped.r = second,
    Color { g, .. } if g == first => swapped.g = second,
    Color { b, .. } if b == first => swapped.b = second,
    Color { a, .. } if a == first => swapped.a = second,
    _ => { /* no match */ },
}
```

Comment: To perhaps clarify the logic behind this — Rust's matches have two "modes": when comparing against a literal or a `const` identifier, they do equality checking; any other identifier gets bound to the value at runtime. So `Color { r: 10, .. } => {...}` and `Color { r: my_const, .. } => {...}` would only match if the runtime value of `r` matches `10` or `my_const`, whereas `Color { r: my_let, .. } => {...}` always succeeds and binds `my_let` to the runtime value of `r`.